# unique or distinct for collections in squeak(Smalltalk)

Tags: collections, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

there is a method like `uniq` in bash for collections in squeak?

to remove all duplications in the collection and get a collection with one of each distinct obj.

For example:

**before:** `#('cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat')`

**after:** (uniq) `#('cat', 'dog')`

Comment: Yes, there is `#withoutDuplicates`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exist quite a few ways of doing the same in subtly different ways, depending on your needs. The more popular ones I can think of are:

- `aCollection asSet` creates a new `Set` with all the elements of the collection, and sets by definition have only one instance of each element.
- `aCollection removeDuplicates` removes the duplicates from the *original* collection itself. This only works if the collection is not of a fixed size (i.e. it doesn't work on arrays).